# Hayek influenced by?

Tags: political-economy

I am going to write an essay about Hayek's views on economic and political (individual) liberty. I am trying to find books to develop a positive discussion on the topic, but I do not know where to search. I started with J.S. Mill's "on Liberty" and Hobbes' "Leviathan", but I cannot find where Locke discuss subjects such as individualism. Also, I was thinking about reading anarchist idea on the topic as an opposing view. Is there any good reading I've missed so far?

Comment: What's wrong with the wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Hayek  infobox `influence` reference?

Comment: You know, there's a dinstict difference between calling names and citation on a specific topic. According to wiki, tell me how hayek influenced by Locke?

Comment: Unless you have the resources to dig out all Hayek published works and cross reference with all Locke coined sentences.  But you can try your lucks by googling "Hayek Locke".

Comment: This question seems like it might be a better fit for [Politics.SE].

Comment: The Road to Serfdom has an index which gives a couple of page references for Locke.  It also has a Bibliographical Note mentioning, among many others, Lippmann, de Tocqueville and Lord Acton.

Comment: @Adam Bailey I did not know that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hayek's The Constitution of Liberty is in my opinion the place to start. It has a lot of references to John Stuart Mill (which whom he strongly disagrees, btw), and puts forward his argument on freedom. There is also a very recent (but rather long) analysis of Hayek's book (available online [here](http://iea.org.uk/sites/default/files/publications/files/Hayek%27s%20Constitution%20of%20Liberty.pdf)), which dissects his influences.